# Buttons has no background on Safari iOS

Tags: css, reactjs, safari, mobile-safari

I'm having an issue with buttons on iOS devices in Safari, the background color does not get applied as it does on Desktop and Android devices.
Here are the CSS properties on the button

```
export const Button = styled.button`
  display: inline-block;
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.text.main};
  margin-left: 8px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.palette.main};
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;

  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  opacity: 1;
`
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using bootstrap .btn ?
Then try using background or background-color in your css file.

```
.btn{
  background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: That's just a regular HTML button. I added the full list of CSS properties to my initial question